# How can I access viewcontroller's NSTimer from TabBarController in Swift

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new on Swift. I have a Tab Bar Controller in my ios app. I am starting NSTimer in my first tab which name is as HomePageViewController as below :

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad(){
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer(){
        print("stop timer")
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer=nil
    }

    func reStartTimer(){
        print("restart timer")
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer=nil
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "updateTimer", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
```

My didSelectItem method in TabBarController.swift  is  :

```
    override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {

if item == (self.tabBar.items![0]){
//necessary operation
}

else {
homePageVC.stopTimer()
    }
```

but timer doesn't stop. How can I stop timer from TabBarViewController ?

Answer (score 0):

You should invalidate your timer. See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-SW3).

```
if item == (self.tabBar.items![0]){
    //necessary operation
} else {
    homePageVC.invalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I fixed problem :

```
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
        let homePageVC = self.viewControllers![0] as! HomePageViewController

        if item == (self.tabBar.items![0]){
            if (lastSelectedTabItem==0){
            }
            else{
                homePageVC.reStartTimer()
            }
        }
        else {
            homePageVC.stopTimer()
        }

        if(item.title=="Tab1"){
            lastSelectedTabItem=0
        }
        else if(item.title=="Tab2"){
            lastSelectedTabItem=1
        }
        else if(item.title=="Tab3"){
            lastSelectedTabItem=2
        }
        else {
            lastSelectedTabItem=3
        }

    }
```